# NSInternalInconsistencyException, how to resolve this exception?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
UIImagePickerController *controller=[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
[controller setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
[controller setEditing:YES];
[controller setDelegate:self];    

[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
[controller release];
```

Hi, I am new in iPhone technology, I am using this code to capture the image from the camera, but when I click on the use button I get the sigmabt error.

I am also using this delegate mathod to get the image:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    imagePhoto.image=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];    
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Be good to see the exact error stack.

Answer (score 0):

```
    UIImagePickerController *controller=[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    controller.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    controller.editing=YES;

    controller.delegate=self;


    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

    [controller release];
```

try with dot syntax UIImagePickerController has synthesized all of the properties.

Comment: please check with device not in simulator.

Answer (score 0):

I cant tell anything, but you Should place a breakpoint and see which line of code causes the crash. If I would guess, I think it's something with the init or release. (As I said, just a wildly guess)

And as @madhu said, make sure your not trying to access the camera roll on the simulator. Use another directory or make sure you're testing on device.